# Kivy 1.9.1 on El Capitan

Tags: kivy, osx-elcapitan, info.plist, nsdocumentcontroller, cfbundledocumenttypes

I'd recently upgraded to El Capitan, and was going to upgrade to the most recent Kivy. After following the [OSX installation instructions](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html), I entered `$/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/MacOS/Kivy` in Terminal, which crashed with the following error message

```
2016-05-21 16:58:39.406 Kivy[29012:817803] NSDocumentController Info.plist warning: The values of CFBundleTypeRole entries must be 'Editor', 'Viewer', 'None', or 'Shell'.
2016-05-21 16:58:39.419 Kivy[29012:817803] Application did finish launching
2016-05-21 16:58:39.421 Kivy[29012:817803] Running task
/bin/bash '/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/script'
2016-05-21 16:58:39.491 Kivy[29012:817803] Task finished
2016-05-21 16:58:39.491 Kivy[29012:817803] Output empty
```

Out of interest, I opened Info.plist, and CFBundleTypeRole does not appear anywhere. What steps should be taken to get Kivy running?

Comment: you don't actually run kivy.app directly. Either drag a python script onto it, or launch the kivy app from terminal using the symlink (step 4).

Comment: Ok. This version works slightly differently. then. Before, if I double clicked on Kivy.app, it would appear on the dock, and then I could drop a ``.py`` onto it. That is not the case anymore.